# New Hero for the League of Justice... Business of Software man?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, league-of-justice

Is there any talk of a Business of Software arm for the S[OFU] League of Justice?

See questions like <strike>[this](https://superuser.com/questions/33710/internet-ads-allowed-on-sites-with-log-in-closed)</strike>, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092959/recommended-books-about-the-software-business), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128150/finding-a-partner-for-a-for-profit-software-project) and <strike>[this](https://superuser.com/questions/12305/how-to-start-a-software-company-closed)</strike> for examples of the what would be more appropriate there.

Comment: Please note: The questions on SU have now been deleted.

Comment: @Diago - thanks for the heads up. Is there a cached copy I can link to for demonstration purposes? Google doesn't have the the "cached" link on S[OFU] search results

Answer (score 2):

Programmers SE didn't exist when you asked this question, but today, it fills the niche you're asking about.

According to [its FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq), Programmers welcomes questions about "freelancing and business concerns" (among other topics) that apply to all programmers (but aren't broad enough to apply to all careers, period).

Answer (score 0):

When StackExchange goes public, feel free to make one (perhaps it is even one of the ten private beta ones already in progress).

Comment: The difference in subject matter is too narrow for someone else to do this. It would be trivial for Joel and Jeff to turn around and wipe out a separate B of S site. "Filling little gaps in another company’s product lineup is snatching nickels from the path of an oncoming steam roller."

Comment: I bet if they were dimes and quarters he'd be all over that.

Comment: Maybe it would be trivial to you to whip out, but you must also consider that guidelines must be established, moderators must be found, and you have yet another site to support. That doesn't really sound trivial, and I don't think that they should keep rolling out new sites whenever someone decides they have questions which don't necessarily fit in with the current sites and their guidelines. "You mean I can't post about apples here? Damn we really need FruitOverflow now!"

Comment: Oh, man... If there's one thing i love on my waffles more than syrup, it's applesauce!

Comment: @TheTXI - The point is it wouldn't be trivial for _me_. It would be a ton of work. Where as Joel already has substantial ties to Business of Software related site and even a B of S conference with his name on it. The audience is built in and its a natural extension of the existing sites. Unlike ponyoverflow or fruitoverflow or waffleoverflow.