# Is there an official position regarding whether or not we can ask legal questions on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, legal

To be clear, I am asking if there is an official position - not what you think the position should be or if you think there should be a position at all. :)  If there is an official position, please point me towards it because I cannot find it.

I have read [this thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19886/not-the-place-for-legal-questions), but I am not sure if the positions people take here are official or just their opinions

Comment: It's only OK if you don't care about getting a correct answer.

Comment: Yeah... You can try asking medical questions here too - *if you want to **die**.*

Comment: "How to operate triple bypass surgery programmatically?" @sho

Comment: @random Damn.  I have a script for double, but not triple.

Comment: I would consult your lawyer as to whether you should ask legal questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I would consult SO first as to whether I should consult my lawyer as to whether I should ask legal questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Question for stackoverflow: Is it legal for programmers to give each other legal advice on a programming q&a site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official position on what kinds of questions you should and shouldn't ask on Stack Overflow is in the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: thanks.  i did look at the FAQ, but I didn't see anything pertaining to legal issues.  i'm guessing legal questions would fall under two categories:

1) matters that are unique to the programming profession
2) questions that are subjective, argumentative, or require extended discussion.

I guess #2 trumps #1 in all cases?

Comment: @sqlnoob: actually, if they're unique to the programming profession, then by definition they aren't legal questions (because otherwise they would be relevant to the legal profession as well...)

Comment: @Shog9: well, if you can get sued (successfully) over it I'm sure it concerns lawyers, regardless of how programming-specific it may be...